# Finding highest Open after swing Low is broken

Tags: pivot, pine-script

The above code fails with error message.
Any help will be helpful

```
//@version=4
study("count", overlay = true)
swh = pivothigh(high,2,1)
swl = pivotlow(low,2,1)
Bcount = barssince(swh)
// plot(Bcount)
highestOpen = valuewhen(crossunder(low,swl), highest(open,Bcount+1),0)
plot(highestOpen)
```

Comment: Please post the full error message so people can help you debug.

Comment: Study Error : Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0.0) in the 'highest' function. It must be >0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that at first bars `Bcount = barssince(swh)` is 0.

```
//@version=4
study("count", overlay = true, max_bars_back = 100)
swh = pivothigh(high,2,1)
swl = pivotlow(low,2,1)
Bcount = nz(barssince(swh))
// plot(Bcount)
highestOpen = valuewhen(crossunder(low,swl), highest(open,Bcount+1),0)
plot(highestOpen)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It helped a lot in understanding the barssince functionality appropriately.